# 7z - compress files in sub-directory, name them for parent folder

Tags: windows, 7-zip, recursive

I'm trying to compress a folder structure like so:

```
Root
 |_ Folder
      |_Sub Folder 1
          |_Files
      |_Sub Folder 2
          |_Files
      |_ *more Sub Folders*
```

I need to create .zip file for each Sub Folder that contains the files within the Sub Folder, and needs to be named for the Sub Folder.  So if I run the command within "Folder", I'd get a zip file named for each Sub Folder, with the contents of the Sub Folder only (not the Sub Folder just zipped up).

I've tried various for commands on Windows using 7-zip but can't seem to get it.

```
for /d %i in (*) do 7z a -oC:\Temp... %i.zip
```

That just zips the entire Folder contents and loops through creating an archive for each sub-folder name.

I appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to install TotalCommander (from ghisler's site), select desired subdirs (may use * on numeric keyboard to toggle all). Alt-F5 shortcut to compressors. Check "Create separate archives, one per selected file/dir", select desired compressor and OK.

In a Batch you can use:

```
@echo off
for /d %%i in (*) do (
    echo Compressing %%i
  7z a "C:\TEMP\%%i.7z" -r "%%i\*.*"
)
```

Or in a CMD line:

```
for /d %i in (*) do  7z a "C:\TEMP\%i.7z" -r "%i\*.*"
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you!

Comment: Thanks, -r is necesary to recurse subDirs, and -o (output dir option) won't work because I think it's only a decompressing option. Please add quotes (forgotten last set) which are necessary if some DIRs have spaces in their name. Also try TotalCommander which will ease that and other common tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Powershell :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Root\Folder" -Force -Directory -ErrorAction Continue | foreach {Start-Process "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -ArgumentList "a C:\TEMP\$_.7z -r $($_.FullName)\*.*"}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I tried this in PowerShell but it end up creating empty zip files for each sub-directory.  Thank you though!