# Loop through folders compressing subdirectories and renaming after parent folder

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, compression, zip

I have a directory of folders as follows:

```
ABC-2000-001-01.pax
|_FolderA
  |_Files
|_FolderB
  |_Files

ABC-2000-001-02.pax
|_FolderA
  |_Files
|_FolderB
  |_Files

ABC-2000-001-03.pax
|_FolderA
  |_Files
|_FolderB
  |_Files
```

I need a command that zip FolderA and FolderB and rename it after the parent folder, like so:

```
ABC-2000-001-01.pax.zip
|_FolderA
  |_Files
|_FolderB
  |_Files

ABC-2000-001-02.pax.zip
|_FolderA
  |_Files
|_FolderB
  |_Files

ABC-2000-001-03.pax.zip
|_FolderA
  |_Files
|_FolderB
  |_Files
```

I've tried using Total Commander, from the solution here: [7z - compress files in sub-directory, name them for parent folder](https://superuser.com/questions/1697491/7z-compress-files-in-sub-directory-name-them-for-parent-folder) but it ends up flattening the structure and removing the subfolders. The CMD line script included ends up creating an additional level within the zip:

```
@echo off
for /d %%i in (*) do (
    echo Compressing %%i
  7z a "C:\TEMP\%%i.7z" -r "%%i\*.*"
)
```

Comment: Try this script without the `-r` parameter.

Comment: I tried it without the -r parameter and it created a ZIP folder with the following structure: ABC-2000-001-01.pax.zip > ABC-2000-001-01.pax > FolderA/FolderB. I'm trying to eliminate the .pax level from being created. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Try `7z a "C:\TEMP\%%i.7z" "%%i\*"`.